# Why does referencing a variable in NSLog hide an instance variable in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this little snippet of code:

.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic) double *avgSpeed;
```

.m file:

```
double avgSpeed = totalSpeed/ timercount;
NSLog(@"avg speed: @%f", avgSpeed);
```

the NSLog line gives me the error that "Local declaration of avgSpeed hides instance variable", which I am pretty sure means that I'm declaring a variable of the same name as an already declared variable in the same scope.

However, I'm confused as to why I'm getting this issue since I'm not trying to declare another "avgSpeed" variable, I'm trying to REFERENCE it, and print it in NSLog. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have a property or ivar `avgSpeed`?

Comment: yeah i have a property

Comment: On which line is the error, `double avgSpeed = totalSpeed/ timercount;` or `NSLog(@"avg speed: @%f", avgSpeed);`?

Comment: *"since I'm not trying to declare another "avgSpeed" variable"* - actually, you are declaring another `avgSpeed` variable. It's right there in the code you posted: `double avgSpeed = totalSpeed/ timercount;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the property, write

```
self.avgSpeed = totalSpeed / timercount;
NSLog(@"avg speed: @%f", self.avgSpeed);
```

or if you want to use the backing ivar without the synthesized setter

```
_avgSpeed = totalSpeed / timercount;
NSLog(@"avg speed: @%f", _avgSpeed);
```